# Расчет количества слов в тексте

Tags: c++

Необходимо подсчитать количество вхождений каждого слова в тексте.

1. словом считается любая последовательность символов, каждый из которых не входит в множество разделителей. Множество разделителей должно задаваться отдельно (строкой).
2. кодировка - символы однобайтовые
3. текст находится в файле, имя файла задается первым аргументом командной строки
   пример:
   test.exe war_and_peace.txt
4. выводить в stdout, формат <слово> - <сколько раз встретилось>, вывод должен быть отсортирован по словам в лексикографическом порядке

Допустим есть строка и множество разделителей:

```
void main()
{
    string mySentense = "one. two three one, one two";
    string spacersЗlurality[] = { ",", "." };
}
```

Подскажите как хотя бы сделать 4 пункт?

Comment: Какой-нибудь std::map<std::string, int> - наверное то что вам нужно для статистики.

Comment: @dmitrykozyr Только я собирался вам ответить, как вы удалили свой вопрос!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показыывает один из возможных подходов к решению задания в соответствии с пунктом 4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::string mySentense = "one. two three one, one two";
    const char *delimiters = "., \t";

    std::map<std::string, size_t> frequencies;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
          ( pos = mySentense.find_first_not_of( delimiters, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
        )
    {
        auto n = pos;
        pos = mySentense.find_first_of( delimiters, pos );
        std::string word = mySentense.substr( n, pos == std::string::npos ? pos : pos - n );

        for ( char &c : word ) c = std::toupper( ( unsigned char )c );
        ++frequencies[word];
    }

    for ( const auto &p : frequencies ) std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
ONE: 3
THREE: 1
TWO: 2
```

Все, что вам еще нужно сделать, так это считывать файл строка за строкой, используя стандартную функцию `std::getline`

Comment: Спасибо :) На англоязычном сайте удалил вопрос, т.к. уже отчаялся найти там помощь

Comment: @dmitrykozyr  Другой подход, как там правильно было замечено в комментариях, это использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: +1, но формально говоря, задание неоднозначно. Однобайтная кодировка текста гарантирует лишь то, что можно использовать `std::string` без оглядки на Unicode, но не гарантирует, что кодировка файла будет совпадать с кодировкой строки с разделителями.

Comment: @VladD  Я лишь использовал тот пример строки, который указан в вопросе.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Критика не в вашу сторону, а в сторону задания.