# Ошибка компиляции: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void searchCenzur()
{
    char str[80] = "lsasacsalolcassalolasclolcascaslol";
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
       if(str[i] == "l")
       {
           if(str[i+1] == "o")
           {
               if(str[i+2] == "l")
               {
                   j++;
               }
           }
       }
    }

    cout << "количество совпадений: " << j << endl;

}

int main()
{

  searchCenzur();

  return 0;

}
```

> ошибка main.cpp:14:27: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between
>   pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Comment: `str[i]` — символ. `"l"` — строка.

Comment: Одиночные символы кодируются одиночными кавычками (апострофами) -- вот так `'a'`, а не `"a"` (так записывают строки, которые представлены в памяти последовательностью символов, заканчивающиеся двоичным нулем)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так будет правильно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

    void searchCenzur()
    {
        char str[80] = "lsasacsalolcassalolasclolcascaslol";
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == 'l')
            {
                if (str[i + 1] == 'o')
                {
                    if (str[i + 2] == 'l')
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "количество совпадений: " << j << endl;

    }

    int main()
    {

        searchCenzur();

        return 0;

    }
```

> ```
> if (str[i] == "l")
> ```

Вы сравниваете один символ со строкой(набором символов), в с++ так нельзя, только символ с символом и в одной кодировке.

> UPD:

Судя по коду нужно найти количество совпадений подстроки в строке - если Вы хотели решить именно эту проблему, то [готовое решение в соседней теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442615/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5).

Comment: как организовать проверку нормальную тогда ? ))

Comment: @Ugnius Mkrthcan, Я привел правильный пример кода в своем ответе, если Вам нужно найти еще что - то, то опишите что именно Вы хотите сделать, иначе я Вам не смогу помочь.